# Trying to convert a calculator textbox items into int and char ( for + * and such ) or making them separated from start

Tags: c#, textbox, calculator

I got a problem writing a calculator which can show me a equalization in the text box like 
`25*3(6-5)^2` and then put them into different arrays w'o ruining the orders ofc ,

I first tried to make them separated before even putting them into a textbox, so I used this code :

```
namespace CalculatorForDS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int i=0, j=0, x;
        int[] a;
        int[] b;
        char[] c;

        void Process()
        {
            a = new int[100];
            b = new int[100];
            c = new char[100];
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Process();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 1;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 1;
            j++;
            x = a[i];
        }

        private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "(";
            c[i] = '(';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 2;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 2;
            j++;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 3;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 3;
            j++;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 4;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 4;
            j++;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 5;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 5;
            j++;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 6;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 6;
            j++;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 7;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 7;
            j++;
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 8;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 8;
            j++;
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 9;
            a[i] = a[i] * 10^j + 9;
            j++;
        }

        private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ")";
            c[i] = ')';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "^";
            c[i] = '^';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "/";
            c[i] = '/';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int lenght = textBox1.TextLength - 1;
            string text = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + text[i]; 
        }

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "*";
            c[i] = '*';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "-";
            c[i] = '-';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "+";
            c[i] = '+';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ".";
            c[i] = '.';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 0;
            a[i] = a[i] + j * 0;
            j++;
        }

        private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(a[i]);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is, when I write for example: 1 and 5, it shows me 15 in textbox, but then I check the value in my array a[i] using the listbox, and it gives me 12; or 115 = 84!

I really can't figure out whats wrong,

So I thought maybe I can do it another way, and put them in a textbox and then convert the textbox into int and char or something, for the numbers and operands.

My main project is using stacks and use the inputted equalization of textbox1 into postfix version and showing it ,

But since I knew C++ but knew nothing of C# before this project, I thought of trying some simpler codes first and learned few things from net .

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me

Comment: Have you looked up what the ^ operator actually does? Hint: it's the same as in C++, not the same as in VB.

Comment: Why don't you use the split string option. Like 'string[] myNumbers = TextBox.Text.Split(new string[] {"+","-","(",")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);' This way you ll get all numbers. Then you get all operators. And the you calcualte it.

Comment: You may want to use Math.Pow instead of ^ ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But Math.Pow is overkill for what the OP is trying to do. Besides, even if he were to use that instead of ^, there would still be the flaw in the logic (i.e. if the user types 123, the value in a[i] would become 1, 12, and 1203 successively).

Comment: well Tnx guys :D i got this thing working with that Pow function ,  and also learned of problem it had at inputs like 123 , i gave up on this way and just use textbox to string and char instead :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did few changes to my program but in the end it still had problems , such as inputs like

> 123

instead of going in as 123 would turn into

> 1203

so i remade my program from the start , and use the

```
String x;
char ch = x[i];
if ( ch == '+' || ch =='-' || ch =='*' || ch == '/' || ch == '^' )
{//Here comes the Operators, as for me it works for pushing operators into stack }
else
{//Here comes the Operands, as for me , it works for putting them in another String }
```

with this code above , i could do what i wanted to do in my program , which was Turning Infix expression to Postfix :D

Comment: Tnx Bro for this :D and ur help on my Project :D i finally finished the whole thing yesterday :D if u ever Need a source code for a Calculator which can Turn a Infix to Postfix using Stack , then Solve the postfix expression using Binary Tree and give the final Result , Tell me :D